# Order by text with strings and numbers

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to order this by the column "market", but normal "sort_values" from pandas doesn't work. I want to order by set and game. Could you please help?

```
+---+------------------------------+----------+----------+
|   |            market            |  stake   |  profit  |
+---+------------------------------+----------+----------+
| 0 | Game Winner (Set 1, Game 1)  | 1605.50  | -1020.30 |
| 1 | Game Winner (Set 1, Game 10) | 2825.00  | 85.42    |
| 2 | Game Winner (Set 1, Game 11) | 700.00   | 100.00   |
| 3 | Game Winner (Set 1, Game 12) | 2280.40  | 9.60     |
| 4 | Game Winner (Set 1, Game 2)  | 5688.30  | -1516.84 |
| 5 | Game Winner (Set 1, Game 3)  | 2604.00  | -1205.70 |
| 6 | Game Winner (Set 1, Game 4)  | 4638.56  | -1817.72 |
| 7 | Game Winner (Set 1, Game 5)  | 3600.00  | 1488.00  |
| 8 | Game Winner (Set 1, Game 6)  | 8851.72  | -2776.65 |
| 9 | Game Winner (Set 1, Game 7)  | 10477.00 | -2097.00 |
+---+------------------------------+----------+----------+
```

This is my df. The code I used is as follow:

```
test = df.groupby("market")[["stake","profit"]].sum().reset_index().sort_values("market")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using [`natsort`](https://pypi.org/project/natsort/3.4.0/)

```
from natsort import natsorted, ns

l=df.market.tolist()

df=df.set_index('market').loc[natsorted(l)].reset_index()
df
Out[130]: 
                           market     stake   profit
0   Game Winner (Set 1, Game 1)     1605.50 -1020.30
1   Game Winner (Set 1, Game 2)     5688.30 -1516.84
2   Game Winner (Set 1, Game 3)     2604.00 -1205.70
3   Game Winner (Set 1, Game 4)     4638.56 -1817.72
4   Game Winner (Set 1, Game 5)     3600.00  1488.00
5   Game Winner (Set 1, Game 6)     8851.72 -2776.65
6   Game Winner (Set 1, Game 7)    10477.00 -2097.00
7   Game Winner (Set 1, Game 10)    2825.00    85.42
8   Game Winner (Set 1, Game 11)     700.00   100.00
9   Game Winner (Set 1, Game 12)    2280.40     9.60
```

Answer (score 1):

The sort has worked correctly.  Your set and game are combined into a single string.  Strings sort by collating sequence, not by apparent numerical value.  If you want to sort them by those numbers, you must break out the numerical portions, convert them to integers, and sort on *those* values, rather than the concatenated string values.

Is that enough to get you moving?

Comment: How do I split it in a proper way though? I tried using str.split() but it wasn't working properly. Thanks for helping

Comment: You need to be more specific: "it wasn't working properly" tells me nothing about the problem.  Split on spaces; select elements 3 (set) and 5 (game); strip the comma off the set, convert both to `int`.

Comment: Perhaps a better way is to do this conversion on input; store the set and game as separate columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can try reindex based on the extracted numbers:

```
idx = (df.market.str
         .extract(r'(?P<set>\d+),\s*Game\s*(?P<game>\d+)', expand=True)
         .astype(int)
         .sort_values(['set','game'])
         .index)

df.reindex(idx)
```